# Feature extraction from tweets

Tags: python-3.x

I'm using python language to extract emotions from tweets.I have collected tweets using Twitter API and have preprocessed them.now what are the important features to be extracted

Comment: Are you asking what can you extract from a tweet that is important to you?

Comment: we don't know your requirements, so we can't tell you what's important. Emotion-related language, presumably? If you've got an issue with the code which is intended to that, post it here and people can help.